# Stuck on giving permission for each sendMessage

Tags: java, minecraft

As you can see this is for my StaffChat plugin for my BungeeCord network.

As I've tried almost everything, such as trying to bypass BungeeCord, and go over to Bukkit, which won't work.

```
package com.rubicmc.stabchat;

import java.util.Iterator;
import com.rubicmc.stabchat.Main;
import net.md_5.bungee.BungeeCord;
import net.md_5.bungee.api.CommandSender;
import net.md_5.bungee.api.connection.ProxiedPlayer;
import net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.Command;

public class test extends Command {
public test(String name) {
    super(name);
}

public void execute(CommandSender sender, String[] args) {
    if(sender.hasPermission("staffchat.mod")) {
        if(args.length == 0) {
            sender.sendMessage(Main.prefix + "§cUsage: /test §8<§cMessage§8>");
        } else {
            String message = "";

            for(int var5 = 0; var5 < args.length; ++var5) {
                message = message + args[var5] + " ";
            }

            Iterator var61 = BungeeCord.getInstance().getPlayers().iterator();
            ProxiedPlayer p = (ProxiedPlayer) sender;

            while(var61.hasNext()) {
                ProxiedPlayer var6 = (ProxiedPlayer)var61.next();
                if(var6.hasPermission("staffchat.mod")) {
                    var6.sendMessage(Main.prefix + " ▏ " + p.getServer() + "§f§l" + p.getDisplayName() + " §7➠  §c§o" + message);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        sender.sendMessage(Main.prefix + "§cYou are not a moderator or don't have permission to do this!");
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate a little more on what the current problem is. I don't quite seem to understand what you need help with

Comment: When a player sends a message, how can I set a message for each permission?

For Example:
               `while(var61.hasNext()) {
                ProxiedPlayer var6 = (ProxiedPlayer)var61.next();
                if(var6.hasPermission("staffchat.mod")) {
                    var6.sendMessage(Main.prefix + " ▏ " + p.getServer() + "§f§l" + p.getDisplayName() + " §7➠  §c§o" + message);
                }
            }`

Comment: Please avoid using names like var1, var2, ... var22414. Give them proper names to help us and yourself read the code. So what exactly are you trying to do? I don't see anything that *gives* permissions. This method only looks for one. Do you want it to prefix your public chat messages or use an internal staff chat or.. ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want a better way to send the message to anyone with the correct permission?
if yes I think you can use [`org.bukkit.Bukkit.broadcast(String message, String permission)`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/Bukkit.html#broadcast-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).
If not please explain what the question is better